# PHP - DOM, stripping table from html

Tags: html, dom, strip, php

I have a curl script that ends like this:

```
  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  return $data;

}
```

The $data string it a HTML page with a table on that I want to strip so that I can store the data into a MYSQL database, I have tried using DOM with commands such as:

```
  // new dom object
  $dom = new DOMDocument();

  //load the html
  $html = str_get_html($returned_content2);
   $dom->strictErrorChecking = false;


  //discard white space 
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

  //the table by its tag name
  $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 

  //get all rows from the table
  $rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

  // loop over the table rows
  foreach ($rows as $row) 
  { 
   // get each column by tag name
      $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 
   // echo the values  
      echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
      echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
      echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
    } 
}
```

But keep getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /home/sdsd/dfdsfsdfds/sdfsdfs/table.php on line 178

Comment: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Comment: `str_get_html()` is part of simple_html_dom, I believe, _not DOMDocument_.  You want [`$dom-loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Comment: Further, if you want to disable strict error checking, do so _before_ loading the HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't loading the HTML into your `DOMDocument` at all. Remove this line

> $html = str_get_html($returned_content2);

and place this after your `preserveWhiteSpace` line

```
$dom->loadHTML($returned_content2);
```

Before attempting to fetch table rows, you should make sure you've found at least one table, eg

```
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
if ($tables->length == 0) {
    throw new Exception('No tables found');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, such a silly mistake! Must be because its so late at night haha, thanks for the help but still not getting the results that I wanted I have added my table html to my first post if you could take a look? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's rather trivial:

```
//get all rows from the table
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
                 ^^^^^^^
```

When the document has no tables (e.g. an empty document as you do not load anything into it), that `->item(0)` does return `NULL`. The value `NULL` does not have that `getElementsByTagName` method (it's not an object even), hence you see the error message.

Whenever you do something important (or you run into an error), do the needed pre-condition checks. E.g:

```
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
if (!$tables->length) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException('Table expected but not found.');
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I will also add that, thank you!